# Splitting string from character to character

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have string which look like this:

```
a = "<some_tag>Characters_with_different_len_to_split</some_tag>"
```

What i would like to achieve is to get from that string this:

```
a = Characters_with_different_len_to_split
```

I can't do this by substrings, because characters(which are only non-digit chars) between tags has different length.

Thanks!

Comment: Although this might not be the best solution for your problem, you can use regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the tags with an empty string.

```
>>> a = "<some_tag>Characters_with_different_len_to_split</some_tag>"
>>> re.sub(r'<[^<>]*>', '', a)
'Characters_with_different_len_to_split'
```

Comment: I do not suppose such easy answer. Thank you a lot! I will accept answer in 10 min :-)